# Multichoice ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I need to make multichoice listview of contact, and when I click Confirm button the app should insert mobile number to database.

listview fragment code is :

```
public class MonFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == true) {
                explain();
            } else {
                //demander l'autorisation
            }
        } else {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gestion_contact, container, false);

            final ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            final List<String> contacts = retrieveContacts(getActivity().getContentResolver());

            if (contacts != null) {
                list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contacts));
            }

            return rootView;
        }
    } else {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gestion_contact, container, false);

        final ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        final List<String> contacts = retrieveContacts(getActivity().getContentResolver());

        if (contacts != null)
        {
            list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contacts));
        }

        return rootView;
    }
    return null;
}

private List<String> retrieveContacts(ContentResolver contentResolver)
{
    final Set<String> contacts = new HashSet<String>();
    final Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.Data._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER }, null, null, null);

    if (cursor == null)
    {
        Log.e("retrieveContacts", "Cannot retrieve the contacts");
        return null;
    }

    if (cursor.moveToFirst() == true)
    {
        do
        {
            final long id = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data._ID)));
            final String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
            final int hasPhoneNumber = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0)
            {
                contacts.add(name);
            }
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext() == true);
    }

    if (cursor.isClosed() == false)
    {
        cursor.close();
    }

    final List<String> sortedContacts = new ArrayList<String>(contacts);
    Collections.sort(sortedContacts);

    return sortedContacts;
}
private void askForPermission() {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 2);
}

private void explain() {
    askForPermission();

}
```

And my Activity :

```
public class GestionContact  extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gestion_contact);

    //Récupère le fragment permettant d'accèder à la liste des contacts

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentLayout,new MonFragment()).commit();
}
```

I want to make a selected case near the name.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through android developer blocks. For Reference you can use [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html)

It will provide you complete detail about contacts in android.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this code as reference

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, listContent);
        myList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

```
    myList.setAdapter(adapter);
    getChoice.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String selected = "";
            int cntChoice = myList.getCount();

            SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = myList.getCheckedItemPositions();
            for(int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++){ 
                if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) { 
                    selected += myList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";
                }
            }

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }});
```